# Why do pixel dimensions seem different between Photoshop and my OS?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to get the image on the left a size that will fit inside an image mail merge I have created in Microsoft Word. The length for the image "box" in Word seems to be 358px long when I measure it, while the length of the image in Photoshop is over 400px. I'd like to get the 400px down to 358px, but I'm also having some issues with resizing the image.

Anyway, I'm wondering why the image, once added to the mail merge, not only still fit in the Word image box, but it also comes out as less in size than the total length of the box, i.e. Too small?

Bit of a mismatch and I can't seem to fix it :/ Any help most appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop [Option + Command + I] = Image Size. In here you can set the size of the image, and it's scaled to fit.

If you use your thumb on the Option + Command, just tilt your thumb and you're there, with two buttons down, super fast and easy.

Similarly, Canvas (the total size of the image are) can be changed without impacting the size of the content. The shortcut for this is [Option + Command + C].

I mention this because these two are actually logically named and have logical shortcuts. Making them easy to remember. These are two of very few features like this in Photoshop. And you're likely going to need it in a moment...

As to Word cropping the bottom of your image during the merge, this indicates there is both a width and a height limit in the Mail Merge. So you'll need to figure out what that is, and then adjust the Canvas size (and therefore image aspect ratio) accordingly.

If you resize the Image [Option + Command + I] and do the aspect change like that, you'll distort your content. Hence the reason to use Canvas once you know the ideal aspect ratio.

Aspect Ratio is the ratio between Width and Height.

Most commonly you'll hear it mentioned with regards TV/Video content.

16:9 = the most common (1920 * 1080) is the foundational HD 16:9 ratio.

Most designers prefer screens with 16:10 ratios, such as 1920 * 1200 or 2560 * 1600 or the 2880 * 1800 of the Retina Macbook Pros.

The iPad has a 3:2 ratio (2048 * 1536).

Comment: Thank you for this. I followed some of it, but unfortunately the "how to" part remains a bit of a mystery. I'm sure this post will get removed, but is there any way I could offer to pay you to do this for me? I'm "zakgottlieb" on Skype if so. Would be enormously appreciated.

Comment: No need to pay me. Or anyone else. You just gotta accept that this is not going to be automatic. That you need to make a Canvas of the right size, and then push everything into it as you see fit. You'll have to make an assessment of what's right to crop and where to fudge and fill to make things "fit". It would be nice if this could be done automatically... but it won't end well, and will still need fudging after an automatic method of sizing.

Comment: Probably the fastest way to do it is to work with one "template" canvas, and copy and paste into it each image you need... then resize and crop as you need to, then export each with a unique name. A few hours and you could power through dozens, maybe even a hundred of them.

Comment: OK. My ultimate goal is to keep a folder on my hard drive with images being continuously added (at a rate of about 100 per week) that are either batch manually or batch automatically resized to fit certain pixel dimensions, even if it affects the aspect ratio. The way you describe, while it would work, would be incredibly slow as they would need to be done one by one. Is there no way at all to do what I'm thinking of in batches, whether manually or automatically?

Comment: Given you output requirement, you'd have to pre-edit each image you put into that folder to "play nice" with the aspect ratio of your target. If you do that, then yes, it can be automated. This way you're just fronting the work instead of tailing it. But, either way, you're going to need make sure you meet those aspect ratio requirements at some point otherwise weird cropping and/or stretching will be the result of any automation attempts.